# Why is clutter problem intractable for large sample sizes?

Tags: bayesian, mixture-distribution, posterior

Suppose we have a set of points $\mathbf{y} = \{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_N \}$. 
Each point $y_i$ is generated using distribution
$$
p(y_i| x) = \frac12 \mathcal{N}(x, 1) + \frac12 \mathcal{N}(0, 10).
$$
To obtain posterior for $x$ we write
$$
p(x| \mathbf{y}) \propto p(\mathbf{y}| x) p(x) = p(x) \prod_{i = 1}^N p(y_i | x). 
$$
According to Minka's paper on [Expectation Propagation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/ep/minka-ep-uai.pdf) we need $2^N$ calculations to obtain posterior $p(x| \mathbf{y})$ and, so, problem becomes intractable for large sample sizes $N$. However, I can't figure out why do we need such amount of calculations in this case, because for single $y_i$ likelihood has the form 
$$
p(y_i| x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi}} \left( \exp \left\{-\frac12 (y_i - x)^2\right\} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \exp \left\{-\frac1{20} y_i^2\right\} \right).
$$

Using this formula we obtain posterior by simple multiplication of $p(y_i| x)$, so we need only $N$ operations, and, so we can solve this problem for large sample sizes exactly.

I make numerical experiment to compare do I really obtain the same posterior in case I calculate each term separately and in case I use product of densities for each $y_i$. Posteriors are same. See 
[image]
Where am I wrong? Can anyone make it clear to me why do we need $2^N$ operations to calculate posterior for given $x$ and sample $\mathbf{y}$?

Comment: One operation per term and $N$ terms, so we need $O(N) $ operations. Also, I look through Minka's paper and Bishop's chapter on approximate inference again. Both suggest that we want estimate and obtain posterior for $x$.

Comment: Am i understanding correctly that your $y_i$'s are univariate? If so, you can solve this in $O(n\log(n))$ which is considered tractable regardless of $n$

Comment: @Alexey After re-reading this paragraph, I think the author does not mention $2^N$ operations. He just points out that **"the belief state for $x$ is a mixture of $2^N$ Gaussians"**.

Comment: @Procrastinator according to paper we want to use belief propagation, but can't use because we need to proceed mixture of $2^N$ gaussians. Then the question is why do we want to use BP? Another question arises in case we read chapter 10.7.1 in Bishop's PRML or watch [videolecture by Minka](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_minka_ai/). After that the answer isn't this clear.

Comment: @Alexey I think the logic behind this is different. The author describes what happens if you use belief propagation, in order to emphasise some difficulties with it when $N$ is large, and then promoting his "expectation propagation". He mentions that belief propagation requires the use of a mixture of $2^N$ Gaussians for the belief state for $x$ which becomes complicated when $N$ is large. There is no mention to the number of operations required but to the complexity of the belief state for $x$.

Comment: @Procrastinator I think you are right after all, but I hope there exists a more explanatory example for EP, because this one looks a little far-fetched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the paper is saying the wrong thing.  You certainly can evaluate the posterior distribution of $x$ at a known location using $O(n)$ operations.  The problem is when you want to compute moments of the posterior.  To compute the posterior mean of $x$ exactly, you would need $2^N$ operations.  This is the problem that the paper is trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the point that the distribution is a *mixture* of Gaussians:
each sample $y_i$ is either distributed as per $p(y_i | x)$ with probability $1-w$ and as $p_c(y)$ (clutter distribution for $y$, independent of $x$) with probability $w$.

Let $c_i$ be the indicator variable indicating that sample $i$ was draw from 
the clutter distribution; thus, if it's $0$ it indicates that the sample was drawn from $p(y|x)$.  Obviously, if the sample was drawn from the clutter distribution it's value is irrelevant for the estimation of $x$.

It's the presence of the $2^N$ possible joint states for these indicator variables that causes the problem.

Comment: However, we can drop additional $c_i$ variables, because we need to obtain a maximum posterior solution of the problem. Posterior for $x$ has a clear form, so we are not forced to take into account all $2^N$ present states. So, the question is "Why do we need this amount of computations in case we want to find a maximum posterior solution?"

Comment: The maximization needs to be taken over the states for the $c$ variables.

Comment: We don't know $c_i$, so we integrate out (sum up over) $c_i$. This can be done in a direct way, doesn't it?

Comment: Direct yes, but the number of states (terms) grows like $2^N$, which can be computationally problematic.

Comment: We can do this for each observation in an independent way, so we have $O(n)$, not $O(2^n)$ complexity.

Comment: That amounts to a "mean field" approximation.